# Cannot use an array in AppDelegate in ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ibeacon

In the AppDelegate I have the next extension:

```
extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
        let viewController:ViewController = window!.rootViewController as! ViewController
        viewController.beacons = beacons as! [CLBeacon]?

        NSLog("didRangeBeacons");
    }
}
```

And in the ViewController I do:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var beacons: [CLBeacon]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if(beacons != nil){
            println(beacons![0])
        }
    }
}
```

And it doesn't print me anything. But it's not empty, an array. It prints in the logs `didRangeBeacons`. So, what is the problem and how can I access to it?

Comment: Your appdelegate has a method, that has an input variable named beacons, and your viewcontroller has a variable called beacons, and they are not in connection at all besides their name.

Comment: What do you advice me to do? @DánielNagy

Comment: I would create the extension in the view controller

Comment: @DánielNagy can you help me with it? I'm new in the Swift and it would be best practice for me

Answer (score 0):

`CLLocationManagerDelegate`'s method `locationManager(manager:,didRangeBeacons beacons:, inRegion:)` is an asynchronous call. Here you are trying to get the value of `beacons` in your `ViewController` on the `viewDidLoad` method.

It's possible that the method on the AppDelegate fires after the view controller's viewDidLoad does.

Check that `viewDidLoad` is not being called before `locationManager(manager:,didRangeBeacons beacons:, inRegion:)`

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var beacons: [CLBeacon]?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                println("viewDidLoad")
                if(beacons != nil){
                        println(beacons![0])
                }
             }
        }

What comes first in the console? "didRangeBeacons" or "viewDidLoad" ?